# Dotnet Core - nuget: command not found

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Ive installed dotnet core using the [instuctions](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#debian) on my ubuntu machine.
Now ive noticed that nuget is not installed.

```
bash: nuget: command not found
```

On my Mac nuget is available after installing dotnet core.

The reason i want this is that i need to push a package.

How to get nuget on my ubuntu machine?

Comment: try  "mono nuget.exe". http://headsigned.com/article/running-nuget-command-line-on-linux. Maybe you will also need to update mono

Comment: Ok, ive installed mono. But running mono results in a exception "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'"

Comment: Have you ensured that you installed the SDK and not just Runtime? If so, what dotnet core version and what version of Ubuntu are you running.

Answer (score 2):

Dotnet provides `dotnet nuget push` command which pushes a package to the server and publishes it.

This link might be helpful:

- [Dotnet nuget push command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-push)

Answer (score 0):

The dotnet cli contains a bunch of built-in commands that are included in the SDK.  You can list them using `dotnet --help`. You can list the nuget sub-commands with `dotnet nuget --help`.
Nuget.exe is still supported, but only on [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/faqs/nuget-faq).